# Struts 2 Select Box Display Values in Drop Down

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a query regarding select box in struts2.

Currently What I am doing is:

```
    <s:select list="#session.ALLBranchList"
                name="branchDetail.branchCode" id="selectedbranch" value="%{branchDetail.branchCode}"
                headerKey="select"
                headerValue="Select"
                listKey="branchCode"            
                listValue="branchName"
                ></s:select>
```

The output for the above is  all the branch name a populated in the drop down. and when I am submitting the form I am getting the key value as branch code. I am satisfied with this
.
BUT Now

What I want to achieve is  that in the drop down
Values should be populated in this format:
 1-INDIA
 2-USA
 3-UK
 4-KOREA

one way what I can think of is I form a list having the values in this way. But If I don't wish to alter my list or don't want to write java code to achieve it.Is this possible doing by making changes in select tag?
Please suggest a way to achieve this  or what am I thinking is hypothetical..

Comment: The list is an ordered collection and if it has unwanted order of the elements you have to make altering the list some way that the order will be wanted. Better do it in action rather than in JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `listValue="branchCode+'-'+branchName"`.

Your complete code:

```
<s:select list="#session.ALLBranchList"
          name="branchDetail.branchCode" 
          id="selectedbranch" 
          value="%{branchDetail.branchCode}"
          headerKey="select"
          headerValue="Select"
          listKey="branchCode"            
          listValue="branchCode+'-'+branchName" />
```